# Need help in re module of python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I'm trying to use the re module to parse through a file. I tried three version of the code, first 2 version's are not retrieving any O/P. The third version is retrieving only one line. Can someone please have a look?
Version1:

```
import re
file = open('sample.txt', 'r') 
x = file.readline()
while x:
    var = re.findall(r'(?:\*|\*>)\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\/\d+\s+)?(\S+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+\s+.+)[ie]',x)
    x = file.readline()
print(var)
file.close()
```

Version2:

```
import re
file = open('sample.txt', 'r')
x = file.read()
var = re.findall(r'(?:\*|\*>)\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\/\d+\s+)?(\S+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+\s+.+)[ie]',x)
print(var)
file.close()
```

Version3:

```
import re
file = open('sample.txt', 'r') 
x = file.readline()
while x:
    var = re.search(r'(?:\*|\*>)\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\/\d+\s+)?(\S+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+\s+.+)[ie]',x, re.M)
    x = file.readline()
print(var.group(0))
file.close()
```

The data in sample.txt is as below. The network is blank after first line, and when I'm running individually these statements on python shell the regex is working.

---

```
                Oregon Exchange BGP Route Viewer
      route-views.oregon-ix.net / route-views.routeviews.org
```

This hardware is part of a grant by the NSF.
 Please contact help@routeviews.org if you have questions, or
 if you wish to contribute your view.

```
 Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *   64.48.0.0/16     173.205.57.234                         0 53364 3257 2828 i

 *                    202.232.0.2                            0 2497 2828 i

 *                    93.104.209.174                         0 58901 51167 1299 2828 i

 *                    193.0.0.56                             0 3333 2828 i

 *                    103.197.104.1                          0 134708 3491 2828 i

 *                    132.198.255.253                        0 1351 6939 2828 i
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Please also check the formatting of your question.

Comment: i would like to get the Network, next hop and path from the sample.txt. and regarding the formatting i'm unable to fix the file data here. its has lot of spaces and its getting truncated.

Comment: I've formatted the content now, please have a look.

Comment: @tobias_k, im sorry for the formatting. Its actually inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
import re

thelist = [
"*   64.48.0.0/16     173.205.57.234                         0 53364 3257 2828 i",
"*                    93.104.209.174                         0 58901 51167 1299 2828 i",
"*                    193.0.0.56                             0 3333 2828 i",
]

regex = re.compile("\*\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})?\s+([\S]+)\s+([^i]+i)")

for text in thelist:
    match = re.search(regex, text)
    if match:
        print ("yuppers")
        print (match.group(1))
        print (match.group(2))
        print (match.group(3))
        print ("\n")
    else:
        print ("nope")
```

results

```
yuppers
64.48.0.0/16
173.205.57.234
0 53364 3257 2828 i


yuppers
None
93.104.209.174
0 58901 51167 1299 2828 i


yuppers
None
193.0.0.56
0 3333 2828 i
```

Depending on what you actually want to do with each, you can just fiddle with the results.  The regex makes the network optional which might have been tripping you up.  Hopefully this gets you in the right direction!